# Вытаскивание буквы из картинки

Tags: python, opencv, распознавание-символов, машинное-зрение

Всех приветствую. Мучаюсь уже 2 день. Нужно вытащить эти буквы из картинки, но не могу понять как.

То, что я пробовал и это кое-как работает (через раз и то с натягом):

```
    screen = cv2.imread(img_path)

    screen = cv2.resize(screen, (100, 100))

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

    for c in cnts:

        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)

        if len(approx) > 0:
            screenCnt = approx
            cv2.drawContours(screen, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

            break
```

Вообще, в идеале я хотел сделать что-то такое:

что есть:

[image: то, что у меня есть]

то, что мне нужно:

[image: что нужно]

Что "видит" код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде бы, неплохо, но если взять другое изображение с квадратом, немного перекрывающим букву, то он видит уже это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что с этим можно сделать?

Главное - вытащить из него букву. Честно говоря, я уже не знаю, что с этим делать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy

#file = "pFgR2.jpg"
file = "whyJd.jpg"

original = cv2.imread(file)
miniature = cv2.resize(original, (100, 100))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(miniature, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

(_ret, threshold) = cv2.threshold(gray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Бинаризация отсекла букву от фона, выделив фон белым.
# Нам же нужно обратное.
threshold = 255 - threshold

(contours, _) = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Ищем квадрат с буквой.
# Задаем начальные максимальные и минимальные координаты квадрата.
# Осторожно! Ниже только целочисленные значения от 0 до 255.
mins = numpy.array((255, 255), numpy.uint8)
maxs = numpy.array((0, 0), numpy.uint8)

# Проходимся по квадратам контуров.
for rect in contours:
    (x, y, w, h)=cv2.boundingRect(rect)
    
    if x <= 0 or y <= 0:

        # «Глобальный» контур охватывает все изображение,
        # полностью портя вычисление квадрата с буквой.
        continue
    
    # Обновляем координаты квадрата с буквой с учетом квадрата каждого контура.
    maxs = numpy.maximum(maxs, (x + w, y + h))
    mins = numpy.minimum(mins, (x, y))
    
# Теперь мы можем получить итоговое изображение только с буквой.

# Если захотите увидеть контуры буквы на итоговом изображении.
#cv2.drawContours(miniature, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

essence = miniature[ mins[1]:maxs[1], mins[0]:maxs[0] ]

cv2.imshow("essence", essence)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Были кое какие наработки на эту тему. Подогнал под вашу задачу. С предоставленными вами изображениями справляется на нужном вам уровне.

---

Координаты квадрата с буквой так же можно найти с использованием `cv2.MinMaxLoc`. Основная проблема остается в игнорировании «глобального» контура, который охватывает все изображение. В свое время я не решил эту задачу и написал способом выше.

Comment: cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV есть же..

Answer (score 0):

Можно же просто залить рамку на бинаризированном изображении, чтобы остались только символы. А дальше найти положение букв. Выделять контуры нет необходимости.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

file = "pFgR2.jpg"
#file = "whyJd.jpg"

original = cv2.imread(file)
miniature = cv2.resize(original, (100, 100))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(miniature, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(_ret, threshold) = cv2.threshold(gray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
h, w = threshold.shape[:2]
threshold = cv2.rectangle(threshold,(0,0),(w,h),(255),2)
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
cv2.floodFill(threshold, mask, (0,0), 0);
y_nonzero, x_nonzero = np.nonzero(threshold)
essence=miniature[np.min(y_nonzero):np.max(y_nonzero), np.min(x_nonzero):np.max(x_nonzero),:]
cv2.imshow('essence', essence)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```